# Tools seems like a tag for tools. Thoughts?

Tags: discussion, tags

[tools](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tools) seems like an ambiguous meta tag to me. There are only 16 questions in it. Retagged 'em?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Meta tags smell funny.  What a bunch of [tools](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tools).

Answer (score 1):

That would be 176 Questions with the [tools](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tools), but 16 is close enough.

Regardless, the tag is useless and all the questions with only that tag have been closed. It's safe to burninate I think.

Comment: I only see 16. Actually less since I've retagged some. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Follow up: I'm an idiot.

Comment: Can we have a dev do this?